# Extract correct event name for sharepoint events calendar list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, event-receivers, sharepoint-calendar

I created a timer job for sending email daily for an events calendar list in sahrepoint onpremise 2016. When i put following code, it is not giving me exact event name:

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            SPList sPList = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                            SPQuery sPQuery = new SPQuery();
                       //To check for events occurring next day
                        sPQuery.Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Start_x0020_Time\" /><Value IncludeTimeValue='FALSE' Type=\"DateTime\"><Today OffsetDays=\"1\"/></Value></Eq></Where>";
                        SPListItemCollection items = sPList.GetItems(sPQuery);
                        if (items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            string emails = "";
                            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                            {
                                var pName = item["Person Name"].ToString();
                                var eName = item["Event Name"].ToString();
```

The last line for ename fetches something as :

eName = 8;#Event10

I want only "Event10"

Can u pls help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question it seems that type of the column is Lookup.

You can use below code to get value:

```
if (item["Event Name"] != null)
{
    SPFieldLookupValue sPFieldLookupValue = item["Event Name"] as SPFieldLookupValue;
    string eventName = sPFieldLookupValue.LookupValue;
    // eventName will give the value which you are expecting
}
```

Comment: but the sPFieldLookupValue returns null. Yes, Event Name is a lookup column

Comment: is it single allow Lookup or Multi allow lookup?

Comment: multi allow i think. all events created come in it as a dropdown